# Points to keep in mind while solving a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I was solving this complex equation, $z^2 = -i$, where z is a complex number. I solved it to get $z = \sqrt{-i}$. But my teacher solved it by assuming $z = x + iy$ and he got the answer $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \frac{i}{\sqrt2} \space$ and $z = -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{i}{\sqrt2}$ which is very different from my answer. Where am I wrong? Why cannot I solve it like that? What else should I keep in mind while solving a complex equation?

Comment: 1) First thing to note is that, like any square root, you should have two solutions: $\pm\sqrt{-i}$. 2) Have you seen Euler's formula $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ yet? Without that it's difficult to explain what "the square root of $-i$" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Have you seen the square root of -i before?  If not, doesn't it seem strange to give an answer in terms of something you haven't yet explored?  You might ask what squared = (-1 * i).  It would be i * ... something.  What times itself is i?  If you don't know, then how can you answer that?  Whereas, you probably have seen i times a constant, which is the form your teacher gives.  It's also how you'd go about figuring out what the sqrt of i is.

Comment: "Without that it's difficult to explain what "a square root of −i" is supposed to mean."  How so?  A square root of $-i$ would be one of the values of $z$ so that $z^2 =-i$.  The thing is that tells what it *means* but not how to find it.  You certainly don't need eulers formula to solve that.  Just solve $(x+yi)^2 = -i; x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: ... and ho do you know there even *is* a number where $z^2 = -i$.  If I asked you can you solve $x^2 = \text{the empire state building}$ you can't say $x=\sqrt{\text{the empire state building}}$. You have to point out the operation $x^2$ is only defined on certain types of objects. None of those types of objects are mapped to New York Landmarks.  So $x^2 =\text{the empire state building}$ is impossible and meaningless nonsense. The equation has no solution.  So to solve for $z^2 = -i$ you have to demonstrate there *is* a complex number so that $z^2=-i$. So *which* complex number(s) are those?

Comment: @fleablood Ok I understood your point. But how can I transform  $\sqrt{-i}$ in the actual answer? I know Euler's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to begin with we $\sqrt{-i}$ isn't a valid answer.  *Which* complex number, expressed as $a + bi$, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$, *is* that?

This is a bit like answering Solve $x^2- 17 = 64$ and answering $x = \sqrt{64+17}$.  You *just* aren't finished.

Second of all.  All complex numbers (except $0$) could have multiple square roots and $\sqrt{-i}$ doesn't indicate which one you mean.  $\sqrt{complex number}$ is not well-defined and you shouldn't use it.

The question is... which complex number(s) $a + bi$ is it that $(a+bi)^2 = -i$?

.........

Your instructor did that $(x + yi)^2 = x^2 + 2xyi + y^2i^2 = (x^2 -y^2) + 2xy i = -i=0 + (-1)i$ so $x^2 -y^2 = 0$ and $2xy = -1$.

With that we have $x^2 = y^2$ so $x= \pm y$.

And so $2xy = \pm 2x^2 = -1$.  As $x^2 \ge 1$ (because $x$ is real) we must have $2xy =-2x^2$ and $x = -y$ and $-2x^2 = -1$ so $x^2 = \frac 12$ and $x = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and $y = \mp \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

So $x+yi = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \mp \frac 1{\sqrt 2} i = \pm (\frac 1{\sqrt 2} -\frac 1{\sqrt 2} i)$.

Answer (score 2):

By writing that the solution is $\sqrt{-i}$ you have not really solved the problem, which requires you to express it *without* a square root.

I would solve the problem by first converting to polar coordinates ($-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$), taking the square root by halving the exponent ($\sqrt{-i}=\pm e^{-i\pi/4}$) and then converting back to Cartesian form. Note that the complex equation $z^n=a$ always has $n$ solutions if $a\ne0$.

Comment: @silver_surfer +1 to Parcly Taxel's answer, which is based on [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).  While the teacher's method is accurate (and valid), Parcly Taxel's method is better - in fact, the whole point of De Moivre's theorem is to streamline attacking problems like this.